# Associate already existing contacts to b2c signup

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-ad-b2c, dynamics-365, nest-api, dynamics-crm-portals

What I want to achieve : We are creating a custom web application, in which we are using azure active directory b2c as identity provider for our clients. So client register there and login into our web app.
But whoever does a signup in b2c is already a contact in our dynamics 365.
My Question is how do I associate b2c signup with existing contact record in dynamics 365.

Let me explain what I have tried so far.
Created an invitation through crm UI (manually). Contact is getting email of invitation in which we customized template ( included our web app url with invitation code automatically generated in it ) .
how to redeem code and that should link/associate/create an external identity.
Please refer to screen shot. I want to achieve like this. But this was done manually (as we can see in the screenshot that external identity is linked to contact. If I login with 'Stark Ned' external identity then my app knows which contact in crm it is tied to)
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance
[image]

Comment: Please check out this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/azure-ad-b2c#allow-auto-association-to-a-contact-record-based-on-email) which may helps you

Comment: Can you please point me to a url where do I find "Authentication/[Protocol]/[Provider]/AllowContactMappingWithEmail" also just heads up that I am working on a custom web app not power apps.
Actually I have no idea what is this Authentication/[Protocol]/[Provider]/AllowContactMappingWithEmail

Comment: Please check the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/configure/azure-ad-b2c#related-site-settings) near the related site settings and there is an [article](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/debajitcrm/posts/deep-dive-dynamics-365-portal-authentication-with-azure-ad-b2c-provider) which may be helpful. For associate b2c signup with existing contact record in dynamics 365 i dont see any other way with the web app